# Jquery text() method and a conditional statement can't specify an empty string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**myTags.html**

```
<div id="ControlWrapper">
    <p>​</p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p>​​</p>
</div>
```

**myScripts.js**

```
var a  = $("#ControlWrapper").text();
    if (a == ""){do something;}else {do something else;}

<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_txtContent__ControlWrapper_RichHtmlField" class="ms-rtestate-field" style="display: block;" aria-labelledby="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_txtContent_label">
    <p>​</p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p>​​</p>
</div>
```

Hi, i have the above codes in my html and javascrpt files.

I want to get text from an element and save it in a variable then if it is empty it should return false in a conditional statement, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

I need to comapre the text when there is no text inside an element.

Comment: There is a typo as the id tag does not get closed by a trailing `"`

Comment: And can you provide a minimal reproduceable example please

Comment: if (!a) {

    console.log("true value")
}else {

    console.log("false value")
}

Comment: There are some invisible (zero-width) characters inside of the paragraphs in your example. So they are not empty.

Comment: @TiiJ7 how to remove those zero width spaces. any idea

Comment: You can replace all characters which are not text with a regex `a.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '')  == ""`, this will remove all special characters

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze thanks for the help. but regex need to allow shound not replace numbers and special characters

Comment: *when there is no text* - copied and pasted your code to an editor - your text is *not empty*.   Removing the `\u200b` characters and trim()'ing would not help as your HTML contains newlines, which are included in .text().  Simplest solution is to not include the `\u200b` in your output.  But .text() still gives spaces and newlines, which can be trim()'d.   If that's not an option, then use: `.text().replace(/\u200b/g, "").trim()`  though you'll *probably* get other "special characters" at some point.

Comment: It's just a heads up  not a complete solution. I'm positive you'll figure it out now you know the existing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `if (!a) {...}`

`!a` gives `true` when `a` is `undefined`, `null` or empty.

If you're in a browser you can use `console.log('[',a,']');` to see which value `a` has.

Comment: !a is giving false even a is empty

Comment: @rajivgandhi Are you serious? Please try it out yourself. "!" is short for "not" (negation) and "not a" will return true if the value of "a" is false, null, undefined, 0 or '' (empty string)

Comment: the problem is something else that's why your answer does not work

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a = $("#ControlWrapper").text();
  console.log(a);
  if (!a) {
    console.log("true value")
  } else {
    console.log("false value")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ControlWrapper">
  <p></p>
  <p><br></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

This code exactly logs out "false value" as there is no text included inside the HTML node children elements.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, we can use `trim()` (to remove spaces) method to specify a javascript conditional statement like this:

**myScripts.js** and **myDocument.html**

```js
  function getText() {
      var text = $('.element').text();
      if (text && text.trim() !== '') {
          console.log(text);
      } else {
          alert("Empty");
      }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </style>

</head>
<body>
   
    <div class="element" class="element">
    </div>

    <button onClick="getText()">
        Show Text 
    </button>
    
</body>
</html>
```